# BindingExpression path error: 'MyWindowHeight' property not found on 'object'

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I get following error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'MyWindowHeight' property not found on 'object' ''LumelauaPikkused'
>   (HashCode=4119085)'. BindingExpression:Path=MyWindowHeight;
>   DataItem='LumelauaPikkused' (HashCode=4119085); target element is
>   'MainWindow' (Name=''); target property is 'Height' (type 'Double')

XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="VLumelaud"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
          Canvas.Left="10" 
          Canvas.Top="200" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          Cursor="Hand">
</ComboBox>
```

C#

```
private void LisaVarustusClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    #region LisaLumeLaud

    String lisaLumel = _LisaLumelaud.Text;
    lpp.Lumelauapikkused.Add(lisaLumel);

    LumelauaPikkused.Add(lisaLumel);
    Console.WriteLine(" mitu lumelauda " + lpp.Lumelauapikkused.Count);

    #endregion

    #region LisaMaeSuusk

    String lisaSuusk = _LisaMaesuusk.Text;
    MSP.Maesuusapikkused.Add(lisaSuusk);

    MaeSuusapikkused.Add(lisaSuusk);
    Console.WriteLine(" mitu maesuuska " + MSP.Maesuusapikkused.Count);
    #endregion

    #region CheckIfTextBoxHasValue

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_LisaMaesuusk.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Lisatud");
        _LisaMaesuusk.Clear();
        DataContext = MSP;
    }

    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_LisaLumelaud.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Lisatud");
        _LisaLumelaud.Clear();
        this.DataContext = lpp;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sisestage vähemalt üks väärtus");
    }

    #endregion
}

namespace Laenutus.ModelsView
{
    public class LumelauaPikkused
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> _lumelauaPikkused;

        public LumelauaPikkused() 
        {
            this._lumelauaPikkused = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Lumelauapikkused
        {
            get { return _lumelauaPikkused; }
            set { _lumelauaPikkused = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: format the code + put the actual code where you bind.

Answer (score 0):

Found anwser, was simple grammaer mistake